# Add and Remove Within Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "_name" : "peter",
    "favourites" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this schema within Mongo, and I'm using Node/Express/Mongoose to manage my stack. I'm new to this particular stack and I have a 'favourite' button on the website I'm building. What's the best way to add/remove from favourites?

Do I really need to setup two routes, one for POST and another for PUT? I'm not sure what the best way is to solve this particular problem, I've done some searching and I've not found anything *that* relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to give you the full answer as it's always good to learn, so I've give you 90% of what I think is what you're looking for. Do a check for the name and if it doesn't exist within the favourites array, do the following:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "username": "walterwhite" },
    {  $push: 
        { 
            favourites: [ { "user_id": "7" } ]
        } 
    } 
)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, "PUSH"!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need routes for any of the actions. It's probably the best practice to use the [HTTP Verbs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.METHOD) (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE etc.). Then your routes would look something like this: (this could be wrapped in a file that contains all routes and later `required` in the main app file (ex. app.js).)

```js
module.exports = function (router) {

router.route('/favourites')
        .get(function (req, res, next) {
            // Code for getting all items
        })

        .post(function (req, res, next) {
            // Code for inserting new item
        })

        .delete(function (req, res, next) {
            // Code for deleting an item
        });
}
```

Then you will need to build a form with fields corresponding to the item's properties and use `POST` as a submit method. You will need it for inserting (adding) new items. The request sent from the form, will send you to the `post` route, where you will handle your logic for appending item to the list.
To implement the deletion you will have to send a `DELETE`, request passing an identifier of  the item you'd want to delete. You will handle this code in the `delete` route.
Of course, the `get` route is for getting all items in the collection for further processing or visualizing.

Comment: That makes it clearer, but one last question, how do I post into a document? I'd like to add to the favourites array and remove from there.

Comment: You will have to define a [Mongoose Schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) and then you can work with the items in the collection like any normal JS object. Here is a [good article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications) in the Scotch's site about developing a basic `CRUD` functionality.

Comment: Okay, but currently I already have Mongoose schema's in place. But If I'm using POST, i don't want to create a new schema for what I'm doing, I just want to POST to an array in that schema.

Comment: Just take a look at the Scotch's article. It is a great example of what you need ;)

Comment: In your case when you have loaded your item just use `item.favourites.push({ user_id: 3 });`

Comment: What do you mean by 'loaded item'?

Comment: Loaded from the collection of items in your MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

you must create an **object id** associated to every **user_id**. you can create such id's using.you can associate multiple models with mongoose [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;


"favourites" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57338c9cc5c8cf74181b4cff"),
        "user_id" : 1
    }, 
    {  
        "_id" : ObjectId("5734588e5a54d45434693a09")
        "user_id" : 2
    }
]
```

either render the page or send a json object as response with the object id in it as per your setup.

```
<a href="#" id="5734588e5a54d45434693a09">user_id-2</a> 
<a href="#" id="57338c9cc5c8cf74181b4cff">user_id-1</a>
```

now you can make an ajax request with the object id when clicked on a particular `<a>` tag.you can achieve this with `jquery`. Then remove the user associated with that id from your favorites.

If you add more details.I can give you a specific answer.

Comment: Can I not just query by the user_id?

Comment: yes, you can.If the user_id is unique.Instead of sending the object id you send the user_id.